# Is it possible to write a pyQt5 plugin for QGIS 2.8?

Tags: qgis, pyqt5

I have just installed QGIS 2.8 and the changelog says Qt5 is now supported in QGIS 2.8.

Can anyone tell me if is it possible to write a pyQt5 plugin for QGIS 2.8?

Has anyone tried to do this?

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible yet. Plugins must be written in PyQt4.